# Field httpRequest in "project package" required a bean of type 'jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, mvn-repo

I'm pretty new to Maven and Java itself.

I'm trying to run my  project's **.jar** file that is produced after running :

1. `maven install clean`
2. `maven package`

When I run the jar file, I get the following error :

[image]

I have tried several solutions online but still cannot make sense of it or how to resolve it. I can edit this question and share my **pom.xml** file if necessary. this is the dependency version I am using :

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@Autowired` from the httpRequest variable in the `ApiController`, you shouldn't have a bean of type `HttpServletRequest`, that's an object that gets created for each request. You can add a `HttpServletRequest` parameter to any method in your controller class that is annotated to be a HTTP method (`@GetMapping`) and Spring will automatically initialize the parameter with a reference to the current `HttpServletRequest`.

Scope `provided` means that the dependency should be provided at runtime by JDK or a container. You have 2 options:

**Option 1**. Remove the scope:

```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Option 2**. Add the dependency to the classpath:

```bash
java -classpath <path_to_jakarta_api> -jar <your_jar>
```

just be careful that the second option overrides the entire classpath so if you have some other jars in your current folder or elsewhere seperate them with `;`.

Example: `-classpath .;lib;<path_to_jakarta>` this will search in current folder, `lib` subfolder, and path

**Option 3**: If you have a web application and use Tomcat keep the `<scope>provided</scope>` since those will be included in the classpath automatically by Tomcat.

Comment: I ran :

java -classpath C:\Users\DixSon\.m2\repository\jakarta\servlet\jakarta.servlet-api\6.0.0\jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar -jar .\target\productpass-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

And it threw the same error. I also tried option 1 and it also threw the same error

Comment: Also remove the `@Autowired` from the httpRequest variable, you shouldn't have a bean of type HttpServletRequest, that's an object that gets created for each request.

Comment: I updated the answer as well, sorry for missing the screenshot :)

Comment: I removed @Autowire and it started running, however i Get this error message when making an api request : 


Cannot invoke \"jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String)\" because \"httpResponse\" is null

Comment: I will need to see the code to answer this one.